# Does Spotify offer an oEmbed API endpoint for their Spotify "Play Button" embed?

Tags: api, spotify, oembed

Does Spotify offer an oembed API endpoint for their Spotify Playbutton?

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/

Answer (score 13):

A bit late, but [now there *is* oEmbed support, yes](https://twitter.com/nicklas2k/status/330094611202723840).

It doesn't seem to be documented yet, but [here's an example](https://embed.spotify.com/oembed/?url=http://open.spotify.com/track/298gs9ATwr2rD9tGYJKlQR):

```
{
    "height": 380, 
    "html": "<iframe src=\"https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:track:298gs9ATwr2rD9tGYJKlQR\" width=\"300\" height=\"380\" frameborder=\"0\" allowtransparency=\"true\"></iframe>", 
    "provider_name": "Spotify", 
    "provider_url": "https://www.spotify.com", 
    "thumbnail_height": 300, 
    "thumbnail_url": "https://d3rt1990lpmkn.cloudfront.net/300/35ff8ecde854e7c713dc4ffad2f31441e7bc1207", 
    "thumbnail_width": 300, 
    "title": "John De Sohn, Kristin Amparo - Dance Our Tears Away - Radio Edit", 
    "type": "rich", 
    "version": "1.0", 
    "width": 300
}
```

The `theme` and `view` parameters don't appear to be supported yet.

Answer (score 5):

No. There is no oEmbed support.

We could probably add that with the rich type. I will add it as a feature request. 
(I work at Spotify)

I agree that feature requests doesn't fit well with Stack Overflow.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm really keen to implement this into the platform I work for.

Comment: Apparently yes. The answer below (one year after my answer) states that there is oembed support, added by one developer quite quickly. It doesn't seem to be mentioned in the official documentation, but it seems to work.